# unique lock is not unlocking inside while(1)

Tags: c++, multithreading, mutex, unique-lock

In the next code the `std::unique_lock lck` is not unlocked in `Manager::CommandShell`, despite being explicitly unlocked. I'm able to get "Entering lock" but not "Inside lock", does anybody knows why unlock is not working? Or perhaps it is and it doesen't work as I thought?

```
std::mutex stdinMutex;
Manager *pman=NULL;

void *StdIn_Reader(void *p)
{
    int nbytes; 

    while(1)    /// Infinite loop
    {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lck{stdinMutex};
        nbytes = read(0,pman->stdin_command,MAXCLIENTMSG);
        if (nbytes > 0)
        {
            pman->stdin_command[nbytes]='\0';
            /// Signal cmd
            pthread_kill(pman->self_id,SIGUSR2);
        }
        lck.unlock();
    }
    return NULL;
}

bool Manager::CommandShell(bool started)
{
    char command[(MAXCLIENTMSG+1)*MAXNUMCOMMANDS];
    // variables to process more than one order in a message (when it happens)

    sigset_t newmask;
    siginfo_t info;
    int rcvd_sig;

    // Mask for block all but SIGUSR1 and SIGUSR2 signals
    sigemptyset(&newmask);
    sigaddset(&newmask, SIGUSR1);
    sigaddset(&newmask, SIGUSR2);

    pthread_sigmask(SIG_BLOCK, &newmask, NULL);

    while (1)
    {
        do{
            rcvd_sig = sigwaitinfo(&newmask, &info);
        }while(rcvd_sig==-1);

        command[0]='\0';

        {   
            cout << "Entering lock\n";
            std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lck{stdinMutex};   
            cout << "Inside lock\n";
            if(strlen(stdin_command)){
                    strcpy(command+strlen(command),stdin_command);
                }
                stdin_command[0]='\0'; 
            }
            lck.unlock();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: your conclusion is wrong. Just because one threads unlocks the mutex, doesnt mean that the other thread must get its turn. THe same thread can unlock and in next iteration immediately lock it again.

Comment: That is true, but then how should I manage the mutex in order to a thread be able to go to StdIn_Reader lock the mutex to prevent unwanted access to stdIn_command, while we do the operations there, then unlock the mutex and go to Manager::CommandShell. There lock the mutex again to prevent access when we are accessing stdIn_command and do the operations there and unlock it afterwards.

Comment: read about producer-consumer patterns. `std::condition_variable` might be a way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general holding a mutex lock whilst performing a blocking operation like `read` will lead to deadlocks.

The easiest solution for your code is likely to read into a temporary buffer then lock the mutex and copy into your data structure:

```
    while(1)    /// Infinite loop
    {
        char temp[MAXCLIENTMSG];
        nbytes = read(0,temp,MAXCLIENTMSG);
        if (nbytes > 0)
        {
            std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lck{stdinMutex};
            memcpy(pman->stdin_command, temp, nbytes)
            pman->stdin_command[nbytes]='\0';
            /// Signal cmd
            pthread_kill(pman->self_id,SIGUSR2);
        }
    }
```